# how to get DotNetNuke ModuleID using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke

All,

I'm developing a dnn 6 module and cannot seem to find any way to get the ModuleID using JQuery. The ModuleID is not in the querystring and seems to be stored in the context. Does anyone know how to get the ModuleID using JQuery if it is not shown in the querystring?

One way I tried to do this is use an asp:label control and in the page load assign the ModuleID to the label, then use JQuery to get that .val() of that label. However, I don't want to have the ModuleID just shown on the page - that is silly! :)

thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply render the ModuleId inside a <script> tag in your View.ascx:

```
<script>
    var moduleId = <%= ModuleId %>;
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the source code to add a moduleId var as shown, you can also derive the module Id from the module container

<div id="dnn_ctr4659_ContentPane"> - in this case the moduleId is 4659.

Using jQuery it would be possible to derive the Id based on this pattern.

Comment: this does not work when you put this code in an external JS file.  Something to consider if you are using a js framework like Angular or Knockout and you want to keep your js viewmodel code in its own file (which is best practice)

Answer (score 0):

Well that would be the only way, if you don't want the id in the page you can also have a hidden span give that class moduleid and then add the moduleid to a data attribute data-moduleid and then read this out using jquery

```
<span class="moduleid" data-moduleid="<%=ModuleControl.ModuleContext.ModuleId%>"></span>
```

Comment: or easier using the earlier answer